# How to change the Math Delimiter font

Tags: math-operators

I am using minion math font to change the operator as minion math.

I successfully changed display math operator like \sum, \int etc.,

But I am unable to change the Minion Math font "Math Delimiter" like

```
\big( \big), \Big( \Big), \bigg( \bigg), \Bigg( \Bigg)
\big[ \big], \Big[ \Big], \bigg[ \bigg], \Bigg[ \Bigg]
\left( \right)
\left[ \right]
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{MXP}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MXP}{minionmath}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{minionmath}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MMlargesymbols}{MXP}{minionmath}{d}{n}
\let\sum\relax
\let\intop\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{MMlargesymbols}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{MMlargesymbols}{"50}
    \def\int{\intop\nolimits}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lgroup} % extensible ( with sharper tips
     {\mathopen}{MMlargesymbols}{"3A}{largesymbols}{"3A}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rgroup} % extensible ) with sharper tips
     {\mathclose}{MMlargesymbols}{"3B}{largesymbols}{"3B}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



I need to fix the minion math font below mentioned Math Delimiters

\begin{align*}
&\big(\sum\frac{a}{b} \big), \Big(\int \frac{a}{b}\Big), \bigg(\frac{a}{b} \bigg), \Bigg(\frac{a}{b} \Bigg)\\
&\big[ \frac{a}{b}\big], \Big[\frac{a}{b} \Big], \bigg[\frac{a}{b} \bigg], \Bigg[\frac{a}{b} \Bigg]\\
&\left( \frac{a}{b}\right)\\
&\left[ \frac{a}{b}\right]
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Current Output:[image]

Now I change the \sum, \int symbols in my current output.

But I am unable to change the font "Math Delimiter". How to fix this issue

Please advise.

Comment: i can't answer your question, but have noticed that something is definitely wrong, since there is no difference in size between `\bigg` and `\Bigg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proper LaTeX support, with the package minionmath.sty (as provided on my website). There's no need for all the stuff between \makeatletter and \makeatother. Just use

```
\usepackage[withamsmath]{minionmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{minionamsmath}
```

in this order (the option "withamsmath" and the small package "minionamsmath" take care with some compatibility issues between minionmath and amsmath). Then all the delimiters will work correctly.

Comment: The OP just wants to use a few symbols from `minionmath`, not the whole set.

Answer (score 2):

I simply copied the definitions of these single glyphs you want from `minionmath.sty`.  You have to undefine the operators before reassigning and you have to consistently replace `largesymbols` by `MNlargesymbols` (you do not want to overwrite `largesymbols`).

For a consistent look and feel, however, I recommend Johannes' approach to use MinionMath as a whole.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MXP}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MXP}{minionmath}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MNlargesymbols}{MXP} {minionmath}{m}{n}

\let\sum=\undefined
\let\intop=\undefined
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{MNlargesymbols}{64}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{MNlargesymbols}{80}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lgroup}{\mathopen}%
  {MNlargesymbols}{70}%
  {MNlargesymbols}{70}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rgroup}{\mathclose}%
  {MNlargesymbols}{71}%
  {MNlargesymbols}{71}

\begin{document}

\[ \sum \int \left( \rule{0pt}{1cm} \right) \]

\end{document}
```

[image]