# How can I avoid MnSymbol to redefine the bracket parenthesis?

Tags: symbols, math-operators, brackets, renewcommand, mnsymbol

I'm trying to save the definition of the square brackets since the package [`MnSymbol`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) redefines it. I think the redefined ones are aesthetically ugly.

I'm looking for a solution similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151076/127473).
A simple and understandable solution is preferable.

How can I apply that solution to the parentheses definition?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
with MnSymbol:  \scalebox{2}{\Big[42\Big]}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: with MnSymbols]

[image: without MnSymbols]

Comment: That one is pretty understandable (wait, in this case you're trying to do something else, namely preserve the *font of a big delimiter*.)

Comment: Do you want to use all of mnsymbol except that delimiter, or only one or two symbols from mnsymbol?

Comment: There's https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310514/how-to-change-the-math-delimiter-font?noredirect=1&lq=1 and [fonts - Importing single symbol from MnSymbol - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/importing-single-symbol-from-mnsymbol) for importing single symbol...

Comment: Similar question: [mtpro - Back to use the original \forall symbol - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316575/back-to-use-the-original-forall-symbol)

Comment: `MnSymbol` is not just a collection of additional symbols; it changes *all* of them in a style that’s appropriate to accompany Minion, not other fonts. If you don’t use Minion, you don’t want to load `MnSymbol`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't particularly straightforward, but it works.

Open LaTeX source code (e.g. in source2e.pdf) and copy the relevant lines. Modify `largesymbols` to `oldlargesymbols` to avoid problems.

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\DeclareSymbolFont{oldlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{[}{\mathopen} {operators}{"5B}{oldlargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{]}{\mathclose}{operators}{"5D}{oldlargesymbols}{"03}

\begin{document}

without MnSymbol:  $\Big[42\Big]$

\end{document}
```

The high-level documentation of the font-setting commands are in [fntguide.pdf](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf).

Comment: Doesn't seem very elegant  as  you have to copy paste code, while you should be able to avoid?

Comment: Although it looks like that LaTeX has a very complex system to select font on \everymath built on top of TeX's font select system, I haven't been able to figure out how to e.g. get the current font.